# Quickly restoring a backup over top of an existing database - error "database in use"

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, restore

I'm working on a set of scripts (in SQL Server Management Studio) to fix certain data inconsistencies in a customer database (SQL Server 2008 R2).

I got a `.bak` file with the database, and I restored that to my system, to e.g. `SampleDatabase`. Now I'm working on my scripts, and after a while, I've fixed most of the issues.

So now I'd like to restore that original `.bak` file again, to be sure all my scripts do run against the original data, and do what they're supposed to do. I close all the Windows in SQL Server Management Studio, open a fresh new query window in my `master` database, and issue my `RESTORE` command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [SampleDatabase] 
FROM DISK = N'c:\tmp\sample.bak'
WITH FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'Sample_PRIMARY' TO N'c:\mssql\Sample_PRIMARY.MDF',  
MOVE N'Sample_LOG' TO N'C:\mssql\Sample_LOG.LDF',
NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5
```

Unfortunately, I now get an error message:

> Msg 3101, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

which seems a bit odd, since I made sure I had closed all the SSMS Windows into that database - why is it still in use?

How can I fix this situation as quickly as possible? The only solution I know that works right now is restarting the `MSSQLSERVER` service - but that's a rather lengthy and somewhat cumbersome process...

Is there another, more efficient, more streamlined way to get this database "out of use" so I can restore the backup over top of it again to check my scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variants of the following which uses `ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` are common:

```
:setvar DatabaseName "SampleDatabase"
:setvar BackupDevicePath "D:\Temp\sample.bak"
:setvar DataFilePath "D:\SQLData\I1\"

USE master;
GO

IF (DB_ID('$(DatabaseName)') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
END
GO

RESTORE DATABASE 
    [$(DatabaseName)] 
FROM  
    DISK = N'$(BackupDevicePath)'
WITH 
    FILE = 1
    , MOVE N'$(DatabaseName)_Data' TO N'$(DataFilePath)$(DatabaseName).mdf'
    , MOVE N'$(DatabaseName)_Log' TO N'$(DataFilePath)$(DatabaseName).ldf'
    , REPLACE
    , STATS = 1;
```

Note [SQLCMD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx) mode.

Comment: Excellent stuff - thanks so much, Mark! I was confident there had to be an easier way - tapping into the dba.se brain pool proved to be my best choice - once again! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try restricting access to restricted_user in the database options.  Do your thing and then set back to multi-user.

Comment: There may be more than 1 restricted user accessing the database, so that may not get you the exclusive control.  You will still need to follow up to get `SINGLE_USER` control.